# Animate sub-elements of an external svg icon in D3js?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have been asked to create a dashboard for visualising the mechanical principles of skiing. The first thing he wants me to do is to visualise air drag involved in skiing. I therefore think it would be nice if I could create a SVG icon of a skier, that can move in different directions. For example, to visualise the effect of a proper arm position in skiing, I want to be able to move the arms more in front of the skier instead of hanging down. Simple 2D graphics.

In D3, like to append images like this.

```
const skier = g
.append('image')
.attr('id', 'skier')
.datum(p3)
.attr('href', skierIconSvg)
.attr('width', 100)
.attr('height', 100)
.attr('transform', 'translate(-50, -40)')
```

But with this approach, I find it tricky to just perform an animation of only one element (E.g. arm) on the svg icon. So my question is is there a way to animate only one element of external svg icon in D3.js?

Comment: images don't support scripting so that's going to be pretty much impossible.

Comment: Aww.. so it isn’t possible to draw an external svg icon, wrap some Elements of It with a g element and then be able to perform the animation on only those g elements?

Comment: How are you planning to "wrap some elements" of an image. An image is opaque, you can't access its contents.

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1014829 - I thought I could add a g element in a svg, perhaps with a classname, and then use d3 to select only that element 

Comment: That uses an iframe, not an image element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible, I created this showcase on how to do it.
I parse the SVG as XML and append its children directly to my trusted XML file. Then, I can select the arm and stick (which have horrible auto-generated ID's - you can change them inside the SVG file itself), and rotate them.

The only truly annoying thing is that the rotate displaces the elements a lot. I fixed that with `transform-origin`, which I manually - through trial and error - set close to the shoulder joint. That way, the arm will rotate around the shoulder, instead of around the top left of the SVG.

```js
// The herokuapp is just a hack to make it work on SO, should be easier
// for you locally
d3.xml('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://cmagelssen.no/skier.svg')
  .then((xml) => {
    const svgEl = d3.select('#mySvg')
      .append('g')
      .attr('id', 'skier')
      .node();
    Array.from(xml.documentElement.children).forEach((el) => {
      svgEl.appendChild(el);
    });
    
    const skierG = d3.select("#skier > g > g");
    const skierArms = d3.select("#skier #ailpBmbkR")
       // Trial an error, but if you get this close to the skier's shoulder,
       // you don't have to do a transform and can easily vary rotation!
      .style("transform-origin", "322px 244px")
      .style("transform", "rotate(30deg)");

    const skierStick = d3.select("#skier #c4PTA7jJrE")
       // Same point as the skier arms!
      .style("transform-origin", "322px 244px")
      .style("transform", "rotate(30deg)");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    console.log('done');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySvg" width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Your knowledge about D3.js is really amazing, Ruben. You provide a solution to all my problems. How did you find the arm in my svg? Is it just a id tag on the svg?

Comment: I just used the element inspector to find the matching path element, the IDs aren't really descriptive

Comment: But in principle. I can draw my Icon in adobe illustrator, save it to svg. Then I can go inside the svg and add id tags to the arms, legs, head, body?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but in theory, you can do exactly that

Comment: I will try this weekend. I will send you an update how it goes.

Comment: https://www.zevross.com/blog/2019/03/21/convert-procreate-illustrations-into-web-friendly-svgs-for-interaction-and-animation/ :)